# Реализация стека в структуре данных на основе статического массива C++

Tags: c++, структуры-данных, стек

Увидел на форме, как одну задачку решили стеком структуре данных через статический массив. Но я не понял, как работает этот стек и его функции. Ну вот к примеру для чего нам нужна переменная `int arrayElementsCount = 0` и как она используется в функциях? Можете пожалуйста объяснить этот код.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#define N 5
using namespace std;
struct WebPage {
    string url;
    int size;
    bool isConnectionSafe;
};

struct Stack {
    WebPage array[N];
    int arrayElementsCount = 0;

    void push(WebPage webPage) {
        if (size() >= N) {
            cout << "Stack is full" << endl;
        }
        else {
            array[arrayElementsCount] = webPage;
            arrayElementsCount++;
        }
    }

    void pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            cout << "Stack is empty" << endl;
        }
        else {
            array[arrayElementsCount - 1] = {};
            arrayElementsCount--;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        if (arrayElementsCount == 0) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    int size() {
        return arrayElementsCount;
    }

    void clear() {
        for (int i = size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            array[i] = {};
        }
        arrayElementsCount = 0;
    }

    WebPage top() {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            return array[arrayElementsCount - 1];
        }
        else {
            cout << "Stack is empty." << endl;
            return { "Null element", 0, false };
        }
    }
};

void print(Stack stack) {
    Stack stackCopy = stack;
    WebPage page;
    for (int i = 0; i < stack.size(); i++) {
        page = stackCopy.top();
        if (page.isConnectionSafe) {
            cout << "Webpage with safe connection: url = " << page.url << " , size is " << page.size << "kb" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "Webpage with unsafe connection: url = " << page.url << " , size is " << page.size << "kb" << endl;
        stackCopy.pop();
    }
}

int main() {
    Stack stack;
    WebPage page;
    stack.push({ "google.com", 139, true });
    stack.push({ "youtube.com", 483, true });
    stack.push({ "yabumaga.pl", 9, false });
    stack.push({ "yaraketa.io", 174, false });
    print(stack);
    cout << endl;
    page = stack.top();
    stack.pop();
    page.isConnectionSafe = true;
    stack.push(page);
    print(stack);
    cout << endl;
    stack.push({ "lol.com", 93, false });
    stack.push({ "linkedin.com", 452, true });
    stack.push({ "indianelephant.in", 872, false });
    print(stack);
    cout << endl;
    stack.pop();
    print(stack);
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        stack.pop();
    }
    print(stack);
}
```

Comment: Если ее убрать — как вы будете знать, где находится *вершина стека*? Куда добавлять элемент, откуда его изымать?...

Comment: `#define N 5` из разряда вещей которые не стоит никогда делать (особенно с однобуквенными названиями). С++ дао: `template <int N = 5> struct Stack {`...

Comment: `using namespace std;` - очень плохая срока. Особенно при том что в коде есть переменная с именем `array` , которое определено в `std`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменная `arrayElementsCount` - это счётчик добавленных элементов в [стек](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO).

Проверка есть ли какие-то элементы в стеки

```
bool isEmpty() {
    if (arrayElementsCount == 0) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Сколько элементов Вы добавили (текущий размер)

```
int size() {return arrayElementsCount;}
```

Функция удаляет последний элемент и уменьшает счётчик `arrayElementsCount` на 1, если стек содержит элементы

```
void pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) { cout << "Stack is empty" << endl; }
    else {
          array[arrayElementsCount - 1] = {};
          arrayElementsCount--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение. Я так посмотрел, что, по сути, проверку на пустоту `bool isEmpty()` можно записать как `bool isEmpty() {return arrayElementsCount == 0;}`. Ничего же не меняется так то, правильно?

Comment: @Д-- Да, правильно

Comment: Ничего не правильно, если вы не инициализируете члены структуры по умолчанию. И pop лучше реализовать иначе.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А как правильно сделать, и что не так с pop? Можете объяснить и на коде показать, пожалуйста?

Comment: И еще я бы упростил функцию clear к вот такому виду: `clear() {amountOfElements = 0;}`. Или это не очень правильно?

Comment: @Д-- `clear() {amountOfElements = 0;}` семантически это правильно, но  к коду могут предъявлятся другие требования. Например защита от эксплойтов с переполнением буфера и scrubbing  - обнуление неиспользуемых областей. `pop()` обычно возвращает  выброшенное значение

Comment: @ARHovsepyan В данном случае она инициализирована  `int arrayElementsCount = 0;`

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie, я не про счетчик а про элементы

Comment: @ARHovsepyan при правильном использовании инварианта это имеет значение только при наличии требований к безопасности. К сожалению, нарушенная инкапсуляция - это неправильное использование. Так что проблема вовсе не в инициализации, а в дизайне класса.

Comment: @Swift - Friday Pie, вы всегда имеете комплекс к вопросам в том плане, что жестко отвечаете на заданный вопрос и более не хотите ничего говорить?.. Часто  нужно быть добрым и оставлять свои уместные замечания на вопросы, которые не были заданы, но остались без внимания. Но в данный момент, вы никак не хотите различать дополнительную поправку(что, как я уже отметил, избавит от многих ожидаемых проблем) от  главного, вы просто хотите делать замечание, что я не поступаю так как вы и не нацеливаюсь только на заданный вопрос.  Хотя бы программисты должны рассуждать логически....

Answer (score 2):

Во первых вы должны иметь определенное состояние экземпляров( то есть сохранить инвариант), чтобы код, использующий его, был предсказуем. Во вторых не нужно в функциях!членах выполнять выводы в консоль, потому что по ходу программы это вам может быть не нужным. Оставьте все выводы на вызывающую функцию.

Самое главное тут в том, что ваш счетчик находится в опасной зоне, и его может изменить любая функция, и от этого ваша программа станет не предсказуем(придется полагаться на то, что  клиент не ошибется). Всегда лучше такие члены скрыть в  закрытой части класса, тогда и не придется дать им длинные имена, потому что они только для разработчика. И вы также должны обеспечивать безопасные лишние вызовы  вставки и удаления.

И вы не обеспечиваете вызовы необходимых функций для константных объектов. Чем лучше решите вопросы,  быстрей и понятней будет код, и не будет лишней писанины.   И, если убрать лишнее (например ваша функция вывода уже получает копию стека, но копирует его еще раз) и исходя из вышесказанного, можно написать что то подобное

```
struct WebPage {
    string url{ "?" };
    int size{};
    bool isConnectionSafe{};
};

struct Stack {
   
    bool isEmpty() const { return  Count == 0; }

    void push(const WebPage& webPage) {
        if (Count < N)
            array[Count++] = webPage;
    }          
        
    void pop() {
        if (Count > 0) 
            array[--Count] = WebPage();              
    }   

    int size() const {   return Count ;  }

    void clear() {
        while(Count)
            array[--Count] = WebPage();
    }
   
    WebPage top() const {
        if (Count)
            return array[Count - 1];
        return array[0];
    }
private:
   
    WebPage array[N];
    int Count = 0;
};

void print(Stack stack) {
    WebPage page = stack.top();
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        cout << "Webpage with"
            << (!page.isConnectionSafe ? " un" : " ")
            << "safe connection: url = "
            << page.url << " , size is " << page.size << "kb" << endl;
    }
    stack.pop();
}

int main() {    
    Stack stack;    
    stack.push({ "google.com", 139, true });
    stack.push({ "youtube.com", 483, true });
    stack.push({ "yabumaga.pl", 9, false });
    stack.push({ "yaraketa.io", 174, false });
     //и если хотите вывод информации
    // if(if(stack.top().url == "?") стек не полон или
    if (stack.size() >= N )
          cout << "Stack is full\n";
    print(stack);
    stack.clear();
    stack.push({ "lol.com", 93, false });
    stack.push({ "linkedin.com", 452, true });
    stack.push({ "indianelephant.in", 872, false });
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

Далеко не идеально в таком состоянии, но направит вас делать лучше.